# How can I improve this Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm writing a little browser game as a project to learn RoR with and I'm quite new to it.

This is a little method that's called regularly by a cronjob.

I'm guessing there should be some way of adding elements to the potions array and then doing a bulk save at the end, I'm also not liking hitting the db each time in the loop to get the number of items for the market again.

```
def self.restock_energy_potions
  market = find_or_create_market

  potions = EnergyPotion.find_all_by_user_id(market.id)

  while (potions.size < 5)
    potion = EnergyPotion.new(:user_id => market.id)
    potion.save
    potions = EnergyPotion.find_all_by_user_id(market.id)
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  Are you looking for something like this?

```
def self.restock_energy_potions
  market = find_or_create_market   
  potions = EnergyPotion.find_all_by_user_id(market.id)
  (potions.size...5).each {EnergyPotion.new(:user_id => market.id).save }
  end    
end
```

Note the triple dots in the range; you don't want to create a potion if there are already 5.

Also, if your potions were linked (e.g. by `has_many`) you could create them through the `market.potions` property (I'm guessing here, about the relationship between users and markets--details depend on how your models are set up) and save them all at once.  I don't think the data base savings would be significant though.

Comment: Yes, this looks close to the solution I'm after, but is there a way to save all the new potions at once? For example, create the extra 3 you need and then do just one database call? Or is this just wanting to micro-optimise?

Comment: @Kirchstein -- Yes, you can do such things by linking them with a belongs_to / has_many setup, but I don't think it saves you much if anything.  At the best you get one big INSERT INTO instead of 1-5 small ones, but I doubt the effect would be measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your market/user `has_many` potions, you can do this:

```
def self.restock_energy_potions
  market = find_or_create_market
  (market.potions.size..5).each {market.potions.create(:user_id => market.id)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

a) use associations:

```
class Market < AR::Base
  # * note that if you are not dealing with a legacy schema, you should
  #   rename user_id to market_id and remove the foreigh_key assignment.
  # * dependent => :destroy is important or you'll have orphaned records
  #   in your database if you ever decide to delete some market
  has_many :energy_potions, :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
end

class EnergyPotion < AR::Base
  belongs_to :market, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

b) no need to reload the association after adding each one. also move the functionality
   into the model:

```
find_or_create_market.restock

class Market
  def restock
    # * note 4, not 5 here. it starts with 0
    (market.energy_potions.size..4).each {market.energy_potions.create!}
  end
end
```

c) also note create! and not create.
   you should detect errors.
   error handling depends on the application.
   in your case since you run it from cron you can do few things
   * send email with alert
   * catch exceptions and log them, (exception_notifier plugin, or hoptoad hosted service)
   * print to stderror and configuring cron to send errors to some email.

```
 def self.restock_potions
    market = find_or_create
    market.restock
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    ...
  rescue
    ...
  end
```